# How to use Bootstrap required field on type "button" instead of submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

**This is my code :**

```
    <form>   
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-10x"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" required="required">     
            </div>
        <br/>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-10x"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" required="required">    
            </div> 
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

`required="required"` is working if I change `button type = "submit"`, but I want to use `button type = "button"` only, as I want to submit the form using `AJAX`. How do I use required field using `button type = "button"` ?

Comment: just a thing, you can write `required` instead of `required="required"`, as it has the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use standard type button "submit" and assign to event of the form "submit" handler, where first call `event.preventDefault()`, to prevent form sending, and then call `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the concept, `button` do not accept any user value in it, so you cannot put `required` field validation on it. Instead you can put `required` validation on `email`, `password` field. On button click these fields are checked whether they have some value in it or not. If not the error is displayed.

This can be achieve by using the `jquery validation` like:

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "email": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: "Please, enter a name"
            },
            "email": {
                required: "Please, enter an email",
                email: "Email is invalid"
            }
        }
    });
```

[Working fildle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/656/)

[Another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jberczel/5dAd3/)

Comment: yes, but i want to validate the fields when i click on a "button type= 'button' " ,  it is only validating when button type is submit. how to validate onClick?

Comment: It is jquery validator not bootstrap validator

Answer (score 0):

When submit a form we can check validation. But if you want to use 
    `type='button'` then please call a `javascript` function to check validation.
    for example:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
   $("#form1").valid();
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aog1tgz1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put validation for CallToAction fields/buttons..instead you can validate input fields where user must fill out some data.

Also there is no necessity to assign `required` value for `required` field..you can simply write `<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" required/>`

Answer (score -2):

check out bootstrap validations in detail here (version 3.2 and later) : http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru